# Is there a Python script that can execute SQR report?

Tags: python, sybase, sqr

I want to break dependency from Sybase `sqr` tool.

Is there a Python script that parses `*.sqr` script and executes it?

Answer (score 0):

No answer for quite a while.
So I wrote [PySQR](https://github.com/alexbuz/PySQR/blob/master/README.md) - simple Python script to interpret (parse and execute) `*.sqr` script.

The only function it implements Sybase database access using `isql` is paginated `*.txt` report generation.

Old script:

```
sqr ${BRASS_DIR}/client_confirm_${SYSTEM}_1.sqr \
    ${BRASS_US_USER}/${BRASS_US_PW} \
    "Jul 19 2017 06:00:00:860AM" \
    "Jul 19 2017 07:37:19:370AM" \
    $(echo $$) \
    ${ALL} \
    -V${SYB_SERVER} -XB -XP  >> /tmp/client_confirm.$$
```

Converted script:

```
./pysqr.py --start_time="Jul 19 2017 06:00:00:860AM" \
    --finish_time="Jul 19 2017 07:37:19:370AM" \
    --pid=1708 \
    --lis_file_name=client_confirm_US.lis
```